# How do I add an XML attribute using DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontract

I have a simple class I'm serializing.

```
 [DataContract(Name = "Test", Namespace = "")]
 public class Test
 {
    [DataMember(Order = 0, Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Test() {}
 }
```

This kicks out the following XML:

```
<Test>
   <Text>Text here</Text>
</Test>
```

What I want is:

```
<Test>
   <Text type="MyType">Text here</Text>
</Test>
```

How do I add attributes the the XML elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't add attributes to a DataContract. You either have to use a class that Implements ISerializable or use the .Net XmlSerializer.

Comment: Depending on the system doing the serialization, it is possible to do what the OP is asking - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858798/datacontract-xml-serialization-and-xml-attributes/4859084#4859084

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer, but you can try to implement IXmlSerializable to fully control output xml format.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by declaring an XElement which has attributes defined in it. Ex:

```
public XElement Text { get; set;}
```

Comment: The code 
`[DataMember(Name = "test")]
public XElement test = new XElement("Root", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });`

yields

`<test>
<Root xmlns="">123</Root>
</test>`

which is probably not what the quenstioner has intended

Answer (score -3):

Add the type attribute with [XMLAttribute] and the element value with [XmlText].

```
public class Test
{
    public text Text;

    public Test()
    {
        Text = new text();
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Test", Namespace = "")]
    public class text
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and did not get Text nor type serialized