# How to serialize/deserialize a C# WCF DataContract to/from XML

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization, deserialization, datacontract

I am developing a WCF service which will be consumed by multiple different client applications. In order to make one functionality work, the server needs to read an XML file into a C# DataContract which is then passed on to the concerned client. As far as I understand from the MSDN website, this is possible but I couldn't find any complete examples. In particular, the website talks about a 'stream' parameter which I don't quite get yet.

My data contract has one property field which is a list of another data contract which has multiple simple property fields.

e.g.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass1 {
        [DataMember]
        public string name;
        [DataMember]
        public int age;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass2 {
        [DataMember]
        public List<MyClass1> myClass1List;
    }
```

My classes look something like this.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858798/datacontract-xml-serialization-and-xml-attributes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example

```
MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1();
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass1));

using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = 
        XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        dcs.WriteObject(writer, obj);
    }
}
```

---

```
Books b = new Books();

DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Books));

try
{
    Stream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\temelm\Desktop\XmlFile.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
    xdw.WriteStartDocument();
    dcs.WriteObject(xdw, b);
    xdw.Close();
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    s += e.Message + "\n";
}
```

Comment: @KirkWoll what does <writer.WriteStartDocument()> do? and what if I only want to append 1 element to the XML file?

Comment: [from metadata] - When overridden in a derived class, writes the XML declaration with the version "1.0". And this code writes only 1 object to the file, if that's what you mean.

Comment: it writes one object but that object is a list of other objects so it's fine. how about reading an existing XML document into a datacontract. any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I got it both working. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: When I try to declare the FileStream and XmlDictionaryWriter without the 'using's it does not write the xml file. any ideas?

Comment: yes - the dispose/close methods flush the file back to disk, don't remove the usings

Comment: i understand that the using concept but i manually flush the FileStream and close it. still does not work. I am actually really curious why it doesn't work :D apart from the disposal is there something else done?

Comment: nope, are you sure you flush/close/dispose the writer and the stream in the same order as in my example? note there are 2 nested usings

Comment: I added a block of code at the end of the question. I am not closing the writer..

Comment: yes, I added your code to the answer - you were missing the line to close the writer - you have to do this, otherwise the data you've written to it stays in its buffer and doesn't get flushed to the stream

Answer (score 2):

This can be useful for you. When you need XElement. For instance when you going append node to XDocument or replece XElement of this document.

```
private XElement objectToXElement(SomeContractType obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SomeContractType);

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            dcs.WriteObject(xw, obj);
            xw.Flush();
            xw.Close();
            ms.Position = 0;
            XElement xe = XElement.Load(ms);

            return xe;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the NetDataContractSerializer which solves a whole bunch of problems when using WCF.

See here [MSDN NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx)

It is typically used for wrapping all kinds of objects and pass it over WCF.

You can use it for wrapping objects into a `byte[]` and transport it over WCF,
on the serverside, you can easily Deserialize the objects and do whatever
you want with them.

Here is a discussion on how to use this Serializer correctly:
[MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f30ecd17-cac0-4cdc-8142-90b5f411936b/)

Code snippets are provided there also!

Comment: WTF, a link to the GERMAN Microsoft site???   you probablye meant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx