# Serialization by DataContract

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract, datamember

What attributes I must used for next class (and/or class members):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "classNamespace")]
public class TestClass
{

    [DataMember(Name = "fieldName1")]
    public string Field1;

    [DataMember(Name = "fieldName2")]
    public string Field2;

    [DataMember(Name = "fieldName3")]
    public EnumType Filed3;

}
```

what would this class serialize to next xml:

```
<TestClass xmlns:a="classNamespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" fieldName1="fieldValue1" fieldname2="filedValue2" fieldName3="fieldValue3" />
```

But not to:

```
<TestClass xmlns:a="classNamespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:fieldName1>fieldValue1</a:fieldName1><a:fieldName2>fieldValue2</a:fieldName2><a:fieldName3>fieldValue3</a:fieldName3></TestClass>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858798/datacontract-xml-serialization-and-xml-attributes.

Comment: No is not. I mustn't use XmlSerializer, only DataContractSerializer.