# how to get Soap Envelope attribute value in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, object

How do I get the SOAP xml attribute value in a wcf service?

```
  <ns3:NotifRQ Status="Commit" 
               xmlns:ns2="http://www.dddd.com/df/dd/" 
               xmlns:ns3="http://www.dd.org/OTA/">

      <ns3:rev>dfdfkkl</ns3:rev>
      <ns3:change>dfdfkkl</ns3:change>
  </ns3:NotifRQ>
```

This is the code  I have now for the data contract:

```
[DataContract(Name = "NotifRQ", Namespace = "http://www.dd.org/OTA/")]
public class NotifRQ
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
    public string ResStatus;
}
```

Comment: can you explain briefly ? what you want to get? or what are you truing to say?

Comment: i need to get above SOAP XML (<ns3:NotifRQ>) attribute 'Status' value in wcf

Comment: how to create class in above attribute in wcf

Comment: i asked SOAP Xml @rene

Answer (score 0):

Your `Status` attribute needs to be a field or property of the `NotifRQ` class and you need to instruct WCF to use the less optimal XmlSerializer instead of the DatacontractSerializer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859084/578411). You achieve that by using the [XmlSerializerFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute_properties(v=vs.90).aspx) attribute on your class.

You can now apply [`XmlAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to a field or property of your class that gets or sets the value of an attribute on the xml element.

Create and annotate your class as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.dd.org/OTA/")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class NotifRQ 
{

   [DataMember, XmlAttribute] 
   public string Status="Commit";

   [DataMember]
   public string  rev;

   [DataMember]
   public string  change;
}
```

Above class will write and read the following wire-format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<NotifRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         Status="Commit">
  <rev>foo</rev>
</NotifRQ>
```